# Binary to Ascii trouble with string builder (JAVA)

Tags: java, binary, ascii, stringbuilder

I have a string and I want to change it to binary but then later in the code I wish to change it back into ascci. How would I do that? Here is my code so far:

```
String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert word");
    String s = word;
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int val = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
        }
        binary.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

So how would I get 'binary' back to String s? Without obviously just typing System.out.println(s);

Thanks
Jay

Comment: First you should start by attempting to change it to ascii.

Comment: You're not converting to "binary", you're converting to a string where one can read bits. That's something different.

Comment: Ok, I'n a bit confused. I'm trying to create an encryption code. So I have 3 arrays. 1st array changes to hexadecimal. That works. The 2nd array changes to binary and that works but I'm also trying to decrypt my encrypted word. I can't seem to change my binary back into a string. @CommuSoft how would I convert it to binary or read the binary as a string? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jay: your question is a bit chaotic, please edit your question and provide more details (be more specific) and provide for instance an example...

Comment: @CommuSoft I edited my question is it more clear now??

Comment: @Jay: see updated answer with demo. On a side note: this is not *encryption*, this is *encoding*...

Comment: @CommuSoft thanks, that solved my problem and this is just one aspect in my encryption program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the content from the `StringBuilder` using `binary.toString()`, so:

```
String text = binary.toString();
```

Next you need to process the binary content.

You first split the string into words:

```
String[] byts = text.split(" ",-1);
```

Next you iterate over the `String`s representing bytes and convert them to real bytes and to characters:

```
int n = byts.length;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    byte dat = 0;
    String byi = byts[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < byi.length(); j++){
        char byij = byi.charAt(j);
        dat <<= 0x01;
        if(byij != '0') {
            dat |= 0x01;
        }
    }
    result.append((char) dat);
}
```

See this [**jDoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/m6) for a working example...